# rendering of material to a gameobject in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting

[image]

I have applied red material to gameobject plane still its showing black colour..can anyone help me out

Comment: I would be more concerned about the `Missing Prefab`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your directional light isn't pointing downwards. Without any light, a plane will appear completely black. Try changing the X rotation of the directional light so that it points down.